# Windows phone 7 emulator and visual studio 2010 attach process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

Opened windows phone Emulator(start >> programs >> Windows Phone SDK 7.1 >> Windows Phone Emulator) and then trying to run Windows Phone 7 app in visual Studio 2010, this is trying to open new emulator, is there anyway to run the app in opened emulator (OR something like attach debug process)

-Edit:

my actual Problem is when i try to run on the emulator, it says "Error:Invalid or missing Rom image", and i found the solution on the net as "permanently delete .dess file under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE path" i tried this but no luck since there is no as such file. (but strange is that sometime back it was running properly :-p)

Comment: Why are you opening Emulator separately? You just simply open VS 2010, write your code and then deploy to the Emulator. I dnt see any reason for opening the emulator separately!!

Comment: agree! but my problem is different please see my edited question.

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an instance of Visual Studio, add a Windows Phone specific project, and then run it. If the Windows Phone SDK was successfully installed, the demo app should run correctly inside the emulator. The emulator is opened automatically by Visual Studio, you do not have to start it manually from the folder it is installed in.